# Implementing Pattern with RegExp in Dart

Tags: regex, routes, dart

I wanted to have a `Pattern` where I could easily get the base path of the pattern, for use with routing, like this:

```dart
var route = new Pattern('/user');
print(route.path)
```

would give `'/user'`, but the pattern would match `r'/user/.*'`.

I pictured this would suffice:

```dart
class Path extends RegExp {
  String _path;
  Path(this._path): super(path.join(_path, '.*'));
}
```

However, `RegExp` is abstract, so it cannot work. But `RegExp` is still instantiable because it's constructor is declared with `factory`. Therefore, I find the only / best solution is to keep a `RegExp` object as a member:

```dart
class Path implements Pattern {
  String _path;
  RegExp _r;
  Path(this._path) {
    _r = new RegExp(join(_path, '.*'));
  }

  Match matchAsPrefix(String string, [int start=0]) {
    return _r.matchAsPrefix(string, start);
  }

  Iterable<Match> allMatches(String str) {
    return _r.allMatches(str);
  }
}
```

But the definition of `RegExp` lists only `allMatches`, as specified by `Pattern`. But doesn't all of `Pattern`s method need to be implemented if `RegExp` is to support `Pattern`?

I wanted to look at the implementation of `RegExp`'s constructor, but it's defined as external, and I can't find the correct file.

So properly formulate my question, is there any way for me to do what I originally intended, to inherit from a non-abstract class implementing Pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is fine how you did it (RegExp as member).

The abstract class with the factory constructor is a construct to prevent deriving from RegExp.

The `external` keyword is a trick to bind to a concrete implementation from somewhere else later (VM or JS, see https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.lkkt75qhbiwh).
This is the reason why the abstract class can be instantiated and why `RegExp` doesn't have to implement all methods in the `regexp.dart` file.

Comment: I see my knowledge of the `external` keyword was too narrow. I thought it could only reference Dart code, so I expected to find an implementation, but if that's written in another language, I'd have to rest. I was hoping to find some good code to learn from.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you look at the `Uri` class or `Path` package, and see if it can't help you with what you want (and if it can't, file a feature request). Working with paths or URIs as strings is likely to be fragile.

Anyway, if I understand you correctly, you want the input `x` to be match `"$x/"` and everything after that. That sounds fairly simple - since it matches to the end of the string, there can only ever be one match per string.

You can write your own `Pattern` implementation:

```
class MyPattern implements Pattern {
  final String _pattern;
  MyPattern(String prefix) : _pattern = "$prefix/";
  Iterable<Match> allMatches(String input) {
    int index = input.indexOf(_pattern);
    if (index < 0) return null;
    return [new _MyMatch(input, this, index)];
  }
  Match matchAsPrefix(String input, [int start = 0]) {
    if (input.startsWith(_pattern, start)) {
      return new _MyMatch(input, this, start);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
class _MyMatch implements Match {
  final String input;
  final Pattern pattern;
  final int start;
  _MyMatch(this.input, this.pattern, this.start);
  int get end => input.length;
  int get groupCount => 0;
  List<String> groups(Iterable<int> indices) {
    var result = <String>[];
    for (int i in indices) result.add(group(i));
    return result;
  }
  String group(int index) { 
    if (index == 0) return input.substring(start);
    throw new RangeError.value(index);
  }
  String operator[](int index) => group(index);
}
```